# How to concurrently get InputStreams from a list of URLs?

Tags: java, multithreading, api, url, concurrency

Currently, I am attempting to return a inputstream that consists of a list of sequenced inputstreams each generated from their own url via an API. The issue is that when done sequentially the API takes a few a second to generate the data. As such, the API waists a few seconds during connection. The structure of the api is like so:

```
www.api.com?q=ENCODEDTEXT
```

I currently have this code to add them sequentially.

```
public InputStream getMP3Data(List<String> synthText){
    InputStream complete = getMP3Data(synthText.remove(0));
    for(String part: synthText){
        complete = new java.io.SequenceInputStream(complete, getMP3Data(part));//Concatenate with new MP3 Data
    }
    return complete;
}
```

getMP3Data(String) is the method I use to access the URL by automatically encoding the URL and fetching the inputstream. The point of getMP3Data(List) is to do the same but with an entire list of data. The issue I have is how to accomplish this with multithreading. I would like to call getMP3Data(String) for each item in the list simultaneously. How would I accomplish this? I do not know the size of the list beforehand. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: This is what I ended up using. Improved the speed of the above code execution by over *900%*.**

```
    /**
 * Gets an InputStream to MP3Data for the returned information from a request
 * @param synthText List of Strings you want to be synthesized into MP3 data
 * @return Returns an input stream of all the MP3 data that is returned from Google
 * @throws IOException Throws exception if it cannot complete the request
 */
public InputStream getMP3Data(List<String> synthText) throws IOException{
    //Uses an executor service pool for concurrency
    ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(synthText.size());
    //Stores the Future (Data that will be returned in the future)
    Set<Future<InputStream>> set = new LinkedHashSet<Future<InputStream>>();
    //Iterates through the list
    for(String part: synthText){
        Callable<InputStream> callable = new MP3DataFetcher(part);//Creates Callable
        Future<InputStream> future = pool.submit(callable);//Runs the Callable
        set.add(future);//Adds the response that will be returned to a set.
    }
    List<InputStream> inputStreams = new ArrayList<InputStream>(set.size());
    for(Future<InputStream> future: set){
        inputStreams.add(future.get());//Gets the response that will be returned, returned.
    }
    return new SequenceInputStream(Collections.enumeration(inputStreams));//Sequences the stream
}


     /**
 * This class is a callable.
 * A callable is like a runnable except that it can return data and throw exceptions.
 * Useful when using futures. 
 * @author Skylion
 *
 */
private class MP3DataFetcher implements Callable<InputStream>{
    private String synthText;

    public MP3DataFetcher(String synthText){
        this.synthText = synthText;
    }

    public InputStream call() throws Exception{
        return getMP3Data(synthText);
    }
}
```

Comment: Google for ExecutorService

Comment: Could you be more specific? Executor service seems great for handling concurrent events, but I do not see how useful it would be in this case. Wouldn't having it modify the InputStreams list throw a concurrentModificationException? Let me point out that the order is important as well.

Comment: Just don't modify the list of input streams, and use .invokeAll(), this way you'll have your tasks in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public InputStream getMP3Data(List<String> synthText){
  List<GetMP3Stream> threads=new ArrayList<GetMP3Stream>();
  // start a thread for each MP3 source
  for(String part: synthText){
    Thread thr=new GetMP3Stream(part);
    thr.start();
    threads.add(thr);
  }
  // collect opened input streams in a list
  List<InputStream> streams=new ArrayList<InputStream>();
  for(GetMP3Stream thr: threads){
    thr.join();
    streams.add(thr.res);
  }
  //Concatenate all input streams 
  return  new java.io.SequenceInputStream(streams);
}

class GetMP3Stream extends Thread {
 String url;
 InputStream res;
 GetMP3Stream (String url) {
   this.url=url;
 }
 public void run() {
   res=getMP3Data(url);
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up using Callables however. Speed up the execution of my benchmark code by 900%!!!